# openssl aes encryption bash command != ruby openssl aes encryption

Tags: ruby, bash, encryption, openssl, aes

I am trying to encrypt the same text using AES w/ the same key and iv. I use the bash approach and ruby's openssl stdlib, and I b64 encode the encrypted result. But the results are different! I am trying to understand why. Here is what I did:

**Ruby (1.9.3-p448)**

```
data = "foobar"
key = ["a8f9f5c5b4c42c75e255a73b6be311e1"].pack("H*")
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(128, :CBC)
cipher.encrypt
cipher.key = key
iv = cipher.random_iv
enc = cipher.update(data) + cipher.final
Base64.strict_encode64(enc)

cipher_key_hex = key.each_byte.map { |b| b.to_s(16) }.join
iv_hex = iv.each_byte.map { |b| b.to_s(16) }.join
```

**Bash**

The -iv parameter is set to the iv_hex value calculated above.

```
$ echo -n 'foobar' > foobar.txt
$ openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -base64 -in foobar.txt -K a8f9f5c5b4c42c75e255a73b6be311e1 -iv 5dc7ff87987c5a25ae73433f11bd6fa
```

=========================================

I double checked the IV is the same in both approaches.

**Ruby output:** rbRIW7iTsNC6LttBQ+Amzg==

**Bash output:** CcSs1+ssEu8FYkcspLeCWw==

What am I missing? This is baffling.

Comment: Oddly, I found ONE IV which results in the identical result in both approaches: 0x7ec1b2ceacbbfff4929dd16f5427dea6. What is special about this IV?

Comment: Could you first try and use 16 bytes for the AES key? A key should not be any other size than 128/192 or 256 bits. There is no default key extension algorithm or suchlike. Why are the keys different in your example?

Comment: updated the question using a 16-byte key. not sure why the other key wasn't 16 bytes. good catch. sadly, problem still exists.

Comment: Are you sure that `b.to_s` always returns 2 characters?

Comment: Turns out that is the issue. Using iv.unpack("H*") to convert the bytes to hex is more robust. Thanks for the help debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `b.to_s` will not return two characters per byte. This means that any byte value less than 16 will be converted into one byte, and if those bytes are concatenated then the hexadecimal digits of different bytes will be combined, resulting in an invalid IV or key. This fact is hidden by the cryptographic API, which may pad the keys and IV to a correct size, instead of rejecting them (as it should).

You can use `unpack("H*")` instead to perform the correct encoding of the bytes to hexadecimal. This is also nicely symmetric to `pack("H*")` used for decoding the hexadecimal values.

Comment: Basically the issue and solution of the asker combined in the comments on the question.